# plotting points on a form

Tags: c#, .net

I want to plot points over an image that are a bit transparent. As in I'm able to see over what area are they present. Is there any way on C# .net platform to do so.??

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way to do it.

```
Image bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100); // sample image, load your real image from file here
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height)); // Just to fill the background on the sample image, remove this

    var transparentColor = Color.FromArgb(127, Color.Blue); // Create a semitransparent color
    using(Brush brush = new SolidBrush(transparentColor))
    {
        // Create the dot
        g.FillEllipse(brush, new Rectangle(10, 10, 25, 25));

        // Create another dot
        g.FillEllipse(brush, new Rectangle(25, 15, 25, 25));
    }
}

myPictureBox.Image = bitmap; // display the image in an Imagebox (optional, you might use your image somewhere else)
```

Comment: this thing works fine.. bt could you please tell me how exactly does it create the transparent effect? is it the statement "color.fromargb".?? also if i want to not use any bitmap is there a way?

Comment: @olive, yes [`FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb.aspx) creates a color, the `127` is the alpha value (transparency channel). There are other overloads for creating colors from `a,r,g,b` individually too, see link for all overloads.

Comment: @olive, you can use any other image instead of the bitmap, I updated my answer a little bit with the type of `bitmap`.